# Application hangs. Need auto reboot

Tags: windows-xp, freeze, reboot

I am running Windows XP Pro SP2. On this I have an application that requires a HASP4 parallel dongle. This works fine. Problem is after a random amount of time, the computer comes back with a HASP not found error. All drivers are installed. It sees the dongle (in fact, every 30 seconds it checks to see if it is there.)

This is for a Care Home, and when it hangs, the Nurses do not get notified that a call cord has been pulled.

What I need is to reboot the computer if the program hangs. Any ideas?